# For loop and Matlab data Import from matfile

Tags: excel, matlab, import

Data {n} was downloaded from the URL and exported to excel (see the code below):

```
url='https://data..../..../....json';
data = webread(url);
fnames = fieldnames(data{1});
out = cell(numel(fnames), numel(data));
for n = 1:numel(data)
    for field = 1:numel(fnames)
        temp = data{n};
        try
            out{field, n} = temp.(fnames{field});
        catch
        end
    end
end
out = [fnames, out];
xlswrite('C:\Users\....\.....\test.xlsx', out, 1, 'A1')
```

If now one wants to download from a list of 10 URLs saved as `URL.m`, how can the above code be added to achieve that? Perhaps using the for loop in MATLAB R2017a?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you could do the following to load your URLs

```
load('C:\...\URL.m');
```

Depending how you saved your list to that `.m` file you then may have some minor variations. If it was a 1D cell array of strings called `URLs`, then this will now be sat in your workspace. You could adapt your code to loop through the URLs like so

```
for u = 1:numel(URLs)
    url = URLs{u}; % Assign the url variable to the next value in URLs
    % --- Between the dashes is exactly the same as your previous code ---
    data = webread(url);
    fnames = fieldnames(data{1});
    out = cell(numel(fnames), numel(data));
    for n = 1:numel(data)
        for field = 1:numel(fnames)
            temp = data{n};
            try
                out{field, n} = temp.(fnames{field});
            catch
            end
        end
    end
    out = [fnames, out];
    % --------------------------------------------------------------------
    xlswrite('C:\Users\....\.....\test.xlsx', out, u, 'A1'); % Write
end
```

You'll notice that I'm using the loop variable within `xlswrite` so that each URL's data is stored in a separate sheet of the workbook. You may adapt this by doing something like keeping track of the number of rows you have already written, and changing `A1` accordingly as the destination cell.